# Is it possible to export a selector from a library that uses NGXS?

Tags: ngxs

I have a library that has a store for my grid data. That library is used within our application. I just tried to use a selector from the library within our application, but its not receiving new data.

So what I want to do is use a selector from my GridState (mistyped it GridStore in my image) from a component in my appication.

[image]

Is this something that is possible? I tried using forRoot in the library, but then nothing loads for the libraries components.

Is it possible to otherwise maybe create another shared library with my complete store, so that I can use the selectors from both projects? Is there some kind of best practice/normal way to do this?